# How to find specific property key in a yaml file using intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml

I have YAML file containing for example below text

```
server:
  port: 8084
  session:
    timeout: 600
```

Assuming there are many yaml files each containing a lot of lines, it is difficult to find certain key, for example 'server.session.timeout'.

I tried to find it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> it won't work because of new line characters and 'port' property betweeen.

Is there a way to find property keys in yaml files?

Comment: Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19614.

Comment: Voted, not sure why it concerns ruby. I think is much more wider function.

Comment: YAML subsystem is historically a part of the Ruby plug-in, therefore all the requests related to this subsystem in IntelliJ IDEA product are logged into Ruby project.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19614 status changed to REVIEW

Comment: The status of the issue was changed to FIXED (in 2018.2 EAP6), but for me the feature doesn't work. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19614#focus=streamItem-27-2930998-0-0

Comment: Search flattened YAML keys (full property name) with "search everywhere"(Press Shift twice). "Find in Path" (Ctrl+Shift+F) only searches plain text.

Comment: @Dmytro Melnychuk Your comment seems to be a valid answer. I edited the question and voted for reopen.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Thanks to Dmytro's comment I found a working solution. It is possible to find proprerties by path expression (dot separated) in yaml files using "Search everywhere" option. It can be invoked by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> key twice or by invoking search menu (by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>) and selecting 'all' tab.

[image]

Comment: The same path can be present in multiple similar yaml files. Is there a way to search for a path in the current file in the editor ?

Comment: @ThCollignon unfortunately I don't know